# Confused about calling a method within a class (PYTHON)

Tags: python, class, methods, return, addition

So i've got a class for dealing with temperatures, it's really basic, but for some reason the conversion of celsius to fahrenheit is failing to return a correct result in one area of the class when it works otherwise.

I'm writing the **add** method, and in order to add two temperatures of different types, they have to be converted. I have a method for switching between celsius and fahrenheit, and it works when I just do that in a test program:

```
Testing celsius method:
Converting to celsius...
Result: Temperature: -12.222222222222221 degrees C

Testing fahrenheit method:
Converting back to fahrenheit...
Result: Temperature: 10.0 degrees F
```

But, if I try to use this to add two different types (extra prints to see what it's doing):

```
def __add__( self, other ):

    if type( other ) != Temperature:
        other = Temperature( other )

    a_scale = self.__scale

    if a_scale == 'F':
        print(self)
        print(other)
        temp_1 = self.fahrenheit()
        temp_2 = other.fahrenheit()
        print(temp_1)
        print(temp_2)
        temp_3 = temp_1.__magnitude + temp_2.__magnitude
        return Temperature( temp_3, 'F' )

    elif a_scale == 'C':
        print(self)
        print(other)
        temp_1 = self.celsius()
        temp_2 = other.celsius()
        print(temp_1)
        print(temp_2)
        temp_3 = temp_1.__magnitude + temp_2.__magnitude
        return Temperature( temp_3, 'C')
```

It will print out that it converted 10 degrees C to 68 degrees F (???)

output:

```
Testing addition
Temp 2 = Temperature: 20 degrees C
Performing temp1 + temp2...
Temperature: 10 degrees F
Temperature: 20 degrees C
Temperature: 10 degrees F
Temperature: 68.0 degrees F
Temperature: 78.0 degrees F
```

This is the fahrenheit method:

```
def fahrenheit( self ):

    if self.__scale == 'F':
        return Temperature( self.__magnitude, 'F')
    elif self.__scale == 'C':
        f = ((self.__magnitude * 9) / 5) + 32
        return Temperature( f, 'F' )
```

And it works perfectly fine as far as I can tell.

Celsius, which is almost identical:

```
def celsius( self ):

    if self.__scale == 'C':
        return Temperature( self.__magnitude, 'C')
    elif self.__scale == 'F':
        c = ((self.__magnitude - 32) * 5) / 9
        return Temperature( c, 'C' )
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening :(

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misreading the output of your own program.  The values outputted are:

```
Temperature: 10 degrees F    # self
Temperature: 20 degrees C    # other
Temperature: 10 degrees F    # temp_1 = self.fahrenheit()
Temperature: 68.0 degrees F  # temp_2 = other.fahrenheit()
Temperature: 78.0 degrees F  # The sum of the above two
```

Thus, 10°F becomes 10°F, and 20°C becomes 68°F, which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the reason is whole number arithmetic. Try `((self.__magnitude - 32) * 5) / 9.0` and `((self.__magnitude * 9) / 5.0) + 32`. I've performed a simple test (w/o class stuff, just math) and it gives correct results.